# Padding and border-radius not working in TCPDF PDF

Tags: html, css, laravel, tcpdf

Well, I am creating `PDF` using `tcpdf` in `Laravel`, so I want to apply `padding` and `border -radius` but these are not applying to PDF.
I want to make a notification circle the same as Facebook notification.

Screenshot: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbzWc.png)

Here is my HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th
            <div class="car-notification"> Cars <span class="notify">1</span></div>
        </th>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.car-notification {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
    .car-notification .notify {
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        right: -20px;
        padding: 5px 9px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
```

Comment: What is the point of a notification bubble on a pdf?

Comment: @geertjanknapen actually its client's requirement, He want to show count in the bubble for better visibility and for the same pattern because bubble is also used in the simple HTML page.

Comment: Is the PDF an exact copy of the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use inline styling in the HTML, I had to do this recently.

i.e.

```
<div style="top:0px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; text-align: center;" class="header">
  <div style="padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px; font-size: 20px; text-decoration: underline; padding-top: 5px">
More HTML
   </div>
</div
```

Not all my classes were rendering correctly and I came to the conclusion that inline styling was a good fix as this code is not really dynamic and requires to always look the same.